# How to not have to press enter when using the call command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, call, enter

I have a simple code running a few batch scripts in succession

```
echo Call 1
call 1.bat
echo Call 2
call 2.bat
echo Call 3
call 3.bat
```

What I would like is that once I run this file it would just do it's thing, without me having to press enter on start and on every call. Is it possible to do this?

I'm a beginner and I can't for the life of me find an answer for this question, so please do excuse me if I missed it.

Comment: `Call` doesn't require pressing enter. Your batch files are programmed to do it.

Comment: I see, okay, thank you

Comment: As the answer mentions, you can join with an '&' to ensure it runs subsequently the call completes

Comment: As the answer mentions, you can join with an '&' to ensure it runs subsequently the call completes

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the other batches you could pipe an echo.

```
For /l %%A in (1,1,3) do (Echo:|Call %%A.bat)&Echo Called %%A.bat
```